# java/guava - start and stop at certain index of iterable/iterator

Tags: java, iterator, guava, iterable

I am looking for an elegant way, possibly with Guava, to wrap an Iterable/Iterator, such that the new Iterable/Iterator

- starts at a certain index, and
- stopts at a certain index.

Guava seems to have the functionality to limit the input (http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#limit(java.lang.Iterable,%20int), but not to start at a given index.  I need a combination of both.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`skip`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#skip(java.lang.Iterable,%20int)) for this purpose.

> Returns a view of iterable that skips its first numberToSkip elements.

For example, the following will gives you an Iterable that skips the first two elements and then limit it to the five next:

```
List<Integer> list = [0, ..., 10];
Iterable<Integer> iterable = Iterables.limit(Iterables.skip(list, 2), 5); //[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Note that the parameters are not considered as *indexes* but rather as the *number* of elements to skip (or limit). But it's easy to calculate the end index if you know how many elements you want to skip.

```
 import static com.google.common.collect.Iterables.limit;
 import static com.google.common.collect.Iterables.skip;

 ...

 static <T> Iterable<T> bounded(Iterable<T> iterable, int startIndex, int lastIndex) {
     return limit(skip(iterable, startIndex+1), lastIndex-startIndex);
 }

 bounded(list, 2, 5)//[3, 4, 5]
```

The latter only makes sense if the underlying data structure orders its elements with indexes (such as an `ArrayList`).

But it could be also an `HashSet`, and it does not make sense to start and stop at a given index in an `HashSet` because it's unordered (i.e don't expect that `limit(skip(mySet, 2), 5)` will gives you the elements `3, 4, 5` back)

---

With [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), you could use the new Stream API which also haves those skip and limit methods.

```
static <T> Iterable<T> bounded(Iterable<T> iterable, int startIndex, int lastIndex) {
      return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
                          .skip(startIndex+1)
                          .limit(lastIndex-startIndex)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I really overlooked the skip function. I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't an efficient way to do this, because iterators are so general-purpose. There's nothing to tell you that the underlying data structure will have any way of jumping into the middle to find a given index. Think about a linked list: the only way you can get to index *k* is by traversing the list.

You'd need to create a wrapper round your `Iterator`, and delegate the interface methods to the underlying `Iterator`, but add some extra logic to the `hasNext()` and `next()` methods, and `remove()` if you need support for removals. The first time you call one of these, it will need to iterate through the underlying list to find the starting index, and set a private flag to indicate that it's done so; it can then return `true` or the element, respectively, if there were enough elements to reach the starting index.

Stopping in the right place is much easier (and efficient): keep a private `int` that tracks the index that you're currently on, and when you hit the end index, have `hasNext()` return `false`, and `next()` throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

If you want to be able to remove elements as you go, that should be easy: you can delegate to the underlying `remove()`, but first check (as above) that you haven't reached the end index.